# Reading Images to a webpage from folder Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, file

I want to read and load a large amount of images from a local folder an Javascript array. The images are **numbered lexicographically and sorted, but are the numbers on them are not consecutive integers, so I don't know the exact file path**. What would be a good solution to read and load everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
var folder = "folder/path/";

$.ajax({
  url: folder,
  success: function(data) {
  
    console.log("success");
    
    $(data).find("a").attr("href", function(i, val) {
    
      if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|JPE?G|png|PNG|gif|GIF)$/)) {

        var output = "<img src='" + val + "'>";
        $("#YourContainer").append(output);
        
      }
      
    });

  },
  error: function(e) {
    console.log(e + " error");
  }
});
```

Comment: It reads all files in a directory and then prints on the screen. It is some standard jquey/ajax.

Comment: They are read in alphabetically. After they are read into the ajax you can change to order however you wish by putting the resulting image names into an array and then do your own desired ordering and then output to wherever you want using a simple for loop.